# How do I use the Graph API to get the Top Videos for my Page like the Insights Video tab does?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

If I view https://www.facebook.com/AlJazeeraAmerica/insights/?section=navVideos I see "Top Videos - Most viewed videos on your Page watched for 3 seconds or more, for videos posted between Sep 21, 2015 and Oct 19, 2015." followed by a table of titles, publish dates, reach, views, and completion %age.

Using the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=AlJazeeraAmerica%2Finsights%2Fpage_video_views&version=v2.5) I can view /AlJazeeraAmerica/insights/page_video_views or AlJazeeraAmerica/insights to get lots of numbers about overall video statistics, but none that break down to the per video level.

How can I reproduce the table from the Video Insights page myself? The goal is to integrate with an internal company stats dashboard that already aggregates stats from various 3rd party services, so it's not viable to only have the data accessible from within this Facebook page.

Comment: You should refer to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights) for the available metrics. If what you are looking for is not there, then it may not be possible (at least with the insights API). You could as well ask in the [facebook developers](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers) group to get ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can first fetch the list of videos for the page using /AlJazeeraAmerica/videos. Then iterate through the returned list of videos to get ID for every video and get insights for each video using /(video_id)/video_insights on the Graph API. You can also make these queries using Python.

Comment: Does it really answer the question ? Request you to go through - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer